# Django 1.3.1 Heroku Postgres error

Tags: django, postgresql, heroku, django-settings

We recently pushed our site to staging and have been struggling to get it up ever since, and the team at Heroku are not really responding in time, so I am turning to the community to see if there is a quick fix.

We scrapped the old one and set up a new stack still with the same issues

```
heroku config
DISABLE_INJECTION: 1
```

**settings.py**

```
import dj_database_url
DATABASES = {'default': dj_database_url.config(default='postgres://localhost')}
DATABASES = {
    'default': {
        'ENGINE': 'django.db.backends.postgresql_psycopg2',
        'NAME': 'mydb',
        'USER': 'myuser',
        'PASSWORD': 'mypassword',
        'PORT': '',
        'HOST': 'localhost'
    },
}
```

Here is the full trace.

```
heroku run python myapp/manage.py syncdb

Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "fundedbyme/manage.py", line 11, in <module>
    execute_manager(settings)
  File "/app/.heroku/venv/lib/python2.7/site-packages/django/core/management/__init__.py", line 438, in execute_manager
    utility.execute()
  File "/app/.heroku/venv/lib/python2.7/site-packages/django/core/management/__init__.py", line 379, in execute
    self.fetch_command(subcommand).run_from_argv(self.argv)
  File "/app/.heroku/venv/lib/python2.7/site-packages/django/core/management/base.py", line 191, in run_from_argv
    self.execute(*args, **options.__dict__)
  File "/app/.heroku/venv/lib/python2.7/site-packages/django/core/management/base.py", line 220, in execute
    output = self.handle(*args, **options)
  File "/app/.heroku/venv/lib/python2.7/site-packages/django/core/management/base.py", line 351, in handle
    return self.handle_noargs(**options)
  File "/app/.heroku/venv/lib/python2.7/site-packages/south/management/commands/syncdb.py", line 90, in handle_noargs
    syncdb.Command().execute(**options)
  File "/app/.heroku/venv/lib/python2.7/site-packages/django/core/management/base.py", line 220, in execute
    output = self.handle(*args, **options)
  File "/app/.heroku/venv/lib/python2.7/site-packages/django/core/management/base.py", line 351, in handle
    return self.handle_noargs(**options)
  File "/app/.heroku/venv/lib/python2.7/site-packages/django/core/management/commands/syncdb.py", line 56, in handle_noargs
    cursor = connection.cursor()
  File "/app/.heroku/venv/lib/python2.7/site-packages/django/db/backends/__init__.py", line 252, in cursor
    cursor = util.CursorWrapper(self._cursor(), self)
  File "/app/.heroku/venv/lib/python2.7/site-packages/django/db/backends/postgresql_psycopg2/base.py", line 140, in _cursor
    self.connection = Database.connect(**conn_params)
  File "/app/.heroku/venv/lib/python2.7/site-packages/psycopg2/__init__.py", line 179, in connect
    connection_factory=connection_factory, async=async)
psycopg2.OperationalError: could not connect to server: Connection refused
    Is the server running on host "localhost" and accepting
    TCP/IP connections on port 5432?
```

Comment: It's doing what you said: connecting to localhost port 5432. Is the database server on localhost? I was under the impression that Heroku's DBs weren't on the same hosts as the application servers.

Comment: Heroku database servers are not on localhost!  See the documentation for Django: https://devcenter.heroku.com/articles/django#database-settings

Answer (score 2):

```
DATABASES = {
    'default': dj_database_url.config(default=os.environ.get('DATABASE_URL'))
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Make sure you have Postgres on your heroku:

```
heroku addons:add heroku-postgresql:dev
```

Figure out database url env variable. It's going to look something like this : HEROKU_POSTGRESQL__URL

```
heroku config | grep POSTGRESQL
```

Update your settings

```
import dj_database_url
import os 

POSTGRES_URL = "HEROKU_POSTGRESQL_<COLOR>_URL"
DATABASES = {'default': dj_database_url.config(default=os.environ[POSTGRES_URL])}
```

Bob is your uncle.

I put together a handy bootstrap for django on heroku. It might be helpful: https://github.com/callmephilip/django-heroku-bootstrap

Happy deploying

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
import dj_database_url
DATABASES = {'default': dj_database_url.config(default='postgres://myuser:mypassword@localhost:5432/mydb')}
```